# How to get the angular-cli generate an extra file during the build

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli

When using firebase messaging, there is a requirement that a file named "fire-messaging-sw.js" be available at the same level as index.html

During development, "ng serve" builds and serves all assets from memory .. how do I get it to also keep this file (without including it into any bundles)

Also when creating a production build, how do I confidure "ng build" to create a empty file and place it in the "dist" directory ?

Answer (score 0):

- when creating a production build, how do I confidure "ng build" to
  create a empty file and place it in the "dist" directory ?

Note: Assumption is that you have empty fire-messaging-sw.js file inside your src folder.

Now inside angualr-cli.json file, you should find something similar.

```
"apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"       
  ],
```

Here assets is used for copying new files.

so you should change to

```
"apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "fire-messaging-sw.js"
  ],
```